Reading PMMl model in Android cause Exception
There is a .PMML Model : random_forest.pmml that generated by these python codes in colab:
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn2pmml import PMMLPipeline
from sklearn2pmml import sklearn2pmml

# Load dataset
iris = load_iris()
X, y = iris.data, iris.target
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Train model
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Create a PMML pipeline
pipeline = PMMLPipeline([("classifier", clf)])

# Save the model to PMML
sklearn2pmml(pipeline, "random_forest.pmml")

I want to use this model in android project by using this library:
https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-evaluator/tree/master
implementation 'org.jpmml:pmml-evaluator-metro:1.6.5'

and implementation:
     val inputStream: InputStream = assets.open("random_forest.pmml")
     val modelEvaluator = LoadingModelEvaluatorBuilder()
        .load(inputStream)
        .build()
     modelEvaluator?.verify()

But at the beginning of building modelEvaluator throws exception:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                 Process: com.example.testapplication, PID: 30485
                 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/awt/Image;
                    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.<clinit>(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:337)
                    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.<init>(RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.java:31)
                    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createTypeInfoSet(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:91)
                    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createTypeInfoSet(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:46)
                    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.<init>(ModelBuilder.java:119)
                    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.<init>(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:55)
                    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:403)
                    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:251)
                    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:77)
                    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1111)
                    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:140)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                    at jakarta.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:274)
                    at jakarta.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:263)
                    at jakarta.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:395)
                    at jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:691)
                    at jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:632)
                    at org.jpmml.model.JAXBUtil.getContext(JAXBUtil.java:107)
                    at org.jpmml.evaluator.LoadingModelEvaluatorBuilder.load(LoadingModelEvaluatorBuilder.java:151)
                    at org.jpmml.evaluator.LoadingModelEvaluatorBuilder.load(LoadingModelEvaluatorBuilder.java:138)
                    at com.example.testapplication.MainActivity.createEvaluator(MainActivity.kt:90)
                    at com.example.testapplication.MainActivity.getCategory(MainActivity.kt:29)
                    at com.example.testapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:23)
                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

